# Laravel PayPal checkout.js how to keep data away from the user

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, paypal

right now my PayPal integration is sloppy, and I have been wondering what I can do to avoid this issue.

So what my code does is, I create a user and a club in the first POST request of the route, they will be inactive until payment is completed and therefor I need their data when a payment has been authorized.

So what I have done is I created two hidden fields on the checkout page, and when the Paypal incontext button is clicked, it grabs those hidden fields and shoots it onto my REST api where it gets handled. However this is putting trust in the user to not adjust these through developer tools or javascript.

Is there a way I can get around using the DOM for these details, and actually do it serverside instead?

Comment: you really need to post your code for us to help but you should be using the PayPal IPN https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ to verify a purchase, what you want to do is send say a hash value of the user to PayPal that will then be sent back with IPN to verify the purchase.

Comment: You lost me with the phrase "trust in the user", no, never, anything within a payment process should be bullet-proof.

Comment: Yea, which is exactly what I want to avoid. Therefor I'm asking if there is another way.

@cmorrissey
I am using https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout with a REST Api I made with their PayPal SDK for PHP. That's it, everything works. I doubt that I need IPN for it when I already get a response directly from the incontext PayPal checkout.